# Trouble with passing data from ViewModel to View and PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am building a very simple blog. For my blog I need two models: comments and messages. I know that to use two models in your view you need a ViewModel but I am having quite some dificulties. For some reason I cant acces both models and the same is for my partial view. Now I am very new to asp.net mvc and know it will propably a stupid mistake but I hope someone can show me what I am doing wrong and most important why!

**Here are my models**

```
namespace Portfolio.Models
{
    public class Messages
    {
        public int MessagesId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public DateTime WhenCreated { get; set; }

        public Messages()
        {
            WhenCreated = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}

namespace Portfolio.Models
{
    public class Comments
    {
        public int CommentsId { get; set; }
        public string Comments_body { get; set; }
        public Messages MessagesId { get; set; }
        public DateTime WhenCreated { get; set; }

        public Comments()
        {
            WhenCreated = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my ViewModel**

```
namespace Portfolio.ViewModels
{
    public class MessageViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Messages> Messages { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**My controller**

```
    namespace Portfolio.Controllers
{
    public class MessagesController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public MessagesController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
        public ActionResult Blog()
        {
            var messages = _context.messages.ToList();

            return View(_context.messages.OrderByDescending(Messages => 
            Messages.WhenCreated));
        }

        public ActionResult Comment()
        {
            var comment = _context.comments.ToList();

            return View(_context.comments.OrderByDescending(Comments => 
            Comments.WhenCreated));
        }
        public ActionResult Post()
        {
            return View();
        }


        //This binds the objects from the database to the values from the 
        view

        [ValidateInput(false)]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formValues)
        {
            try
            {
                Messages message = new Messages();
                message.Title = formValues["Title"];
                message.Body = formValues["editor"];

                Comments comment = new Comments();
                comment.Comments_body = formValues["editor" + 
                message.MessagesId];

                _context.comments.Add(comment);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                _context.messages.Add(message);
                _context.SaveChanges();

           }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Blog");
       }
    }
}
```

**Here is my View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Portfolio.ViewModels.MessageViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Blog";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css/Blog.css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<div class="jumbotron opacity_container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>Latest Posts</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @foreach (var messages in Model)
                    {
                        <div class="jumbotron opacity_container">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        @*Gets the title of the blog post*@
                                        <h2 class="panel-title">
                                        @messages.Title
                                        </h2>@messages.WhenCreated
                                   </div>
@*Gets the body of the blog post and decodes the html of the ckeditor*@

                                <div class="panel-body">
                 @Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(messages.Body))
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
 @*this button gets the id from the database of the 
 Message table this helps to prevent that all the comments from all blogs 
 gets shown and thus shows only the comments that belong to the blog in 
 question*@

                    <button class="btn btn primary"id="@messages.MessagesId"
                    onclick="ShowComments(this.id)">
                    Show Comments
                    </button>

@*this is the container where al the comments are placed in and where you 
can post comments. The comments are placed in the Comment partial view*@
                        <div class="hidden" id="Comm@(messages.MessagesId)">
                            @Html.Partial("_Comment", Model)

@*this button gets the id from the database of the Message table this helps 
to prevent that all the comments from all blogs gets hidden and thus
hides only the comments that belong to the blog in question*@
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" 
                        id="@messages.MessagesId" 
                        onclick="HideComments(this.id)">Hide Comments
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**This is my partial view**

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css/Blog.css" />

<div class="row" id="CommentContainer">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>Post Comment</h3>
 @*The form to post comments*@
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Messages"))
            {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Comment</label>
                @Html.TextArea("editor1", htmlAttributes: new { name = 
               "editor1", id = "editor", rows = "10", cols = "180" })
            </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
              id="PostButton">Post Comment</button>
            }

 @*CKEdito script*@
        <script>
             CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
        </script>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
@*Places al the comments and decodes the html from the ckeditor*@
                @foreach(var comments in Model)
                {
                    <div class="well" id="CommentBox">

@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(comments.Comments_body))
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this PartialView shows the comments while the View shows the blog messages.
So I need to send the data from my messages model to my View and I need to send  and retrieve data from my comments model in my partial view.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: are you getting any sort of error message right now? If so can you share it?

Comment: this is the error message i get MessageViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'Title' and no extension method 'Title' accepting a first argument of type 'MessageViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You have set model property of view to the collection ViewModel class but you are sending collection of comments or messages to the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use your ViewModel in your View, you need to pass it to your view from your controller. You're currently passing in a collection of messages:

```
public ActionResult Blog()
{
    var messages = _context.messages.ToList();

    // Your view is expecting a parameter of type MessageViewModel,
    // but you're passing it an object of type List<Messages>
    return View(_context.messages.OrderByDescending(Messages => Messages.WhenCreated));
}
```

If you want to use your ViewModel try something like:

```
public ActionResult Blog()
{
    // Create a MessageViewModel and assign its properties...
    var viewModel = new MessageViewModel()
        {
           Messages = _context.messages.OrderByDescending(m => m.WhenCreated),
           Comments =  _context.comments
        };

    // Pass the MessageViewModel to your view.
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

You'll also need to update your view:

```
@model Portfolio.ViewModels.MessageViewModel
...
@foreach (var messages in Model.Messages)
...
@Html.Partial("_Comment", Model.Comments)
```

And you'll want to have your partial view take a parameter of
`IEnumerable<Comments>` as it's model:

```
@model IEnumerable<Portfolio.Models.Comments>
```

Be aware that this solution is currently grabbing **all** messages and **all** comments from _context and passing them to the view. You probably will want to filter them (only pass in comments attached to a specific message, etc).

Comment: I have applied your suggestion but I still get the same error. I only have changed the controller not the view so maybe I am calling it wrong in the view?

Comment: I just updated the answer to include some changes to the view and partial view.

Comment: thnx gonna try it right away. I am very new in both c# and asp.net so realy thanks for the help

Comment: So i've tried it and in visual studio when i hover over for example @messages.WhenCreated it shows:  DateTime Portfolio.Models.Messages.WhenCreated{get; set;} so I would think that it got passed right but when I compile i now get the error 
                                                            
IEnumerable<MessageViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'Messages' and no extension method 'Messages' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<MessageViewModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The error points to this part: @foreach (var messages in Model.Messages) what I find strange because in visual studio it shows that it is passed right

Comment: Oops. I forgot to fix that. You are only passing a single MessageViewModel. Change `@model IEnumerable<Portfolio.ViewModels.MessageViewModel>` to `@model Portfolio.ViewModels.MessageViewModel`.

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help. I have been lurking on SO for years but never ask or answer any questions. I'm glad I could contribute! Feel free to mark the answer as accepted (if you're satisfied with it of course).